# Function parameter type in Swift

Tags: swift, function

In Swift Programming Language Guide, under Function Type section, it says “Because the parameter type and the return type can be a tuple type, function types support functions and methods that take multiple parameters and return multiple values.”

Note the use of word "can be" - does it mean parameter type can be something else as well? Or parameter type has to be tuple only?

Comment: it can be a single value

Comment: I think this comment is more aimed at pointing out that return types aren’t constrained to be single values any more than arguments are. Also, bear in mind everything you could say everything is tuple, a single value is kinda just a 1-tuple, hence every value has a .0 property.

Comment: "Single value can be promoted into 1-tuple as well.” I don’t think they are “promoted” to 1-tuples, so much as they _are_ 1-tuples, in so much as 1-tuples exist at all: “If there is only one element inside the parentheses, the type is simply the type of that element. For example, the type of (Int) is Int, not (Int). As a result, you can name a tuple element only when the tuple type has two or more elements.” Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2 Prerelease).”

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity try this: let x = 1; print(x.0).  Tuple doesn't just mean two or above, a tuple can be empty as well.  The requirement to name a tuple is a different issue though.

Comment: @Boon I know, see my 1st comment which mentions the .0 thing. And the naming of single-element tuples isn’t unrelated. Note that you cannot name a single-element tuple _except_ when it’s the argument to a function, then you can (sometimes) – function args aren’t _quite_ the same as regular tuples.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Sorry missed that.  Why do you say "sometimes"? Interesting point on naming for 1-tuple.  So because func allows you to name, is it correct to say that when it's in a the 1-element case, that the parameter type is not a tuple but something else? (or that compiler uses a different rule when specifying 1-tuple in function parameter?)

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fiIvt.png) is an example of what I mean by sometimes.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity I am wondering if Apple uses "can be" because parameter type can also be variadic or in/out, both of which are not tuples.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Your example link somehow doesn't show up anymore, can you list again?

Answer (score 1):

you can either call a function with tuples OR with arguments

e.g.

```
func sum(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
  return a + b
}
```

you could call this:

```
let numbers = (40,2)
sum(numbers)
```

or the old way like

```
sum(40,2)
```

Comment: Based on your example, it looks like multi-value function params are tuples.

Answer (score 0):

A tuple means a set of parameters instead of "single" parameters.

The default way means one value per parameter like this:

```
func setValue( myValue:Int ) { ... }
setValue( 3 )
```

On the other hand a tuple can be more than one parameter:

```
func setValues( myValues:(Int,String) ) { ... }
setValues( (1, "Hello") )
```

So tuples are possible, but the common way is to use only single values

Comment: Tuple can mean no parameter as well though (empty tuple), and a single element can also be called a tuple.  So technically, they can make function parameter strictly tuple based.  As such, I am curious as to whether there is really anything else available for use as function parameter but tuple.